# generated code by hibernate for array without parentheses

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I created a method

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.product WHERE concat(reg_id, inn, kpp, country) " + "alc_volume) ILIKE %?1% ORDER BY array_position(array[?2], id)")

List<Product> searchByPatternOrderId(String pattern, Set<Long> ids, Pageable pageable);
```

hibernate generated a code

```sql
SELECT * FROM public.product 
WHERE concat(reg_id, inn, kpp, country) ILIKE ? 
ORDER BY array_position(array[(?, ?, ?)], id) limit ? offset ?
```

postgresql returning syntax error.

1. What I needing do that hibernate not generated parentherss for array?
2. Is it possible to disable the parentheses anywhere?

Comment: You provide a `Set`. Collections are usually used with the `IN` clause in which case the parentheses are needed. Maybe it works if you pass an actual array

Comment: no, it's not working

Comment: @LockOil Did you find the solution? I spent lots of time, but seems to be it is hibernate 'feature' to wrap list values into parentheses if they not provided in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today, although I didn't find a way to remove the paranetheses, I found a workaround that did the trick for me.
Instead of passing a `Collection` parameter I passed in a CSV string.
In my use case, I needed an array of strings, so this worked...
I replaced `array[?1]` with `string_to_array(?1, ',')`